# Could not resolve dependencies for project X Could not find artifact

Tags: java, maven

I have maven project X and when I add the maven dependency below:

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.paypal.sdk</groupId>
      <artifactId>paypal-base</artifactId>
      <version>1.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
```

the maven project fails to build. It shows the error below:

```
Could not resolve dependencies for project X : Could not find artifact com.paypal.sdk:paypal-base:jar:1.1.0 in central (https://company.jfrog.io/organization/libs-release) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

I checked in the following [link](https://dist.wso2.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/paypal-base/1.1.0/) and the jar was present. So the jar isn't missing from the dependency.

Also I have tried to run:

```
mvn -U clean install
```

And didn't resolve the issue.

Below is the configuration of the settings.xml file in the hidden folder.m2:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<settings>
    <servers>
        <server>
            <username>XUSER</username>
            <password>XPASSWORD</password>
            <id>central</id>
        </server>
        <server>
            <username>XUSER</username>
            <password>XPASSWORD</password>
            <id>snapshots</id>
        </server>
    </servers>
    <activeProfiles>
        <activeProfile>artifactory</activeProfile>
    </activeProfiles>
    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>artifactory</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <repositories>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>https://company.jfrog.io/organization/libs-release</url>
                </repository>
                <repository>
                    <snapshots/>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>https://company.jfrog.io/organization/libs-snapshot</url>
                </repository>
            </repositories>
            <pluginRepositories>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots>
                        <enabled>false</enabled>
                    </snapshots>
                    <id>central</id>
                    <name>libs-release</name>
                    <url>https://company.jfrog.io/organization/libs-release</url>
                </pluginRepository>
                <pluginRepository>
                    <snapshots/>
                    <id>snapshots</id>
                    <name>libs-snapshot</name>
                    <url>https://company.jfrog.io/organization/libs-snapshot</url>
                </pluginRepository>
            </pluginRepositories>            
        </profile>
    </profiles>
</settings>
```

I will appreciate any help in fixing this issue.

Kind Regards,
Rando.

P.S

I did a little experiment. Downloaded the content from [link](https://dist.wso2.org/maven2/com/paypal/sdk/paypal-base/1.1.0/) and place them on the .m2/repository/com/paypal/sdk/1.1.0 folder and the build was successful. I don't know why isn't imported automatically.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quick fix to bypass the problem.

```
<project>
...
</dependencies>

  <repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>mWSO2 Dist</id>
    <name>WSO2 Dist</name>
    <url>http://dist.wso2.org/maven2/</url>
  </repository>
  </repositories>
</project>
```

I check in the maven corporate repository and the PayPal SDK dependency was not present. After adding the PayPal SDK manually in the jfrog artifactory I removed the WSO2 Dist repository from the project pom.xml file.

This solution is better because my project is not dependent on external repository.